# How can I add my fonts to hanami app?

Tags: hanami

I added "selawkl.ttf" font into

> apps/web/assets/fonts

folder.
But, I recieved next error after page load:

> HTTP/1.1 GET 404 127.0.0.1 /fonts/selawkl.ttf

How can I add "selawkl" to Hanami app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved my fonts folder to "public" path and this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify. Because **static resources** like some *(fonts, css, images etc)* are not served by Hanami framework. Its best to put them in the **`public/fonts/`** "for fonts" - folder inside the main **`public`** folder for the server to serve them without hitting Hanami Framework.